# How to group a datatable by a column after it has been initialized

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

So currently i have a datatable that displays alot of timesheets for alot of files, i need to create a function that will group all the data by their respected files, but all example that i have found do this in the initialization of the datatable but i need to do this with a custom created button and fail to find any examples or documentation on how to do it this way

The code will just create a table but i would like to have a button with a value "Group Items" then after the button is clicked it should group all by file

```
$('#data-table-timesheet').DataTable({
            ajax: {
                url: '@Url.Action("GetTimeSheets", "Home")',
                data: function (d) {
                    d.from = $("#DateStart").data('datepicker').getFormattedDate('yyyy-MM-dd'),
                    d.to = $("#DateEnd").data('datepicker').getFormattedDate('yyyy-MM-dd'),
                    d.partyId = parseInt($("#UserId").val())
                },
                dataSrc: 'Data'
                },
                "footerCallback": function (row, data, start, end, display) {
                    var api = this.api(), data;

                    // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
                    var intVal = function (i) {
                        return typeof i === 'string' ?
                            i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
                            typeof i === 'number' ?
                                i : 0;
                    };

                    // Total over all pages
                    total = api
                        .column(8, { page: 'current' })
                        .data()
                        .reduce(function (a, b) {
                            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                        }, 0);

                    // Total over this page

                    pageTotal = api
                        .column(7, { page: 'current' })
                        .data()
                        .reduce(function (a, b) {
                            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                        }, 0);

                    // Update footer
                    $(api.column(7).footer()).html(
                        'R' + parseInt(pageTotal).toFixed(2)
                    );

                    pageTotal = api
                        .column(8, { page: 'current' })
                        .data()
                        .reduce(function (a, b) {
                            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                        }, 0);

                    // Update footer
                    $(api.column(8).footer()).html(
                        'R' + parseInt(pageTotal).toFixed(2)
                    );

                    var uTotal = api
                        .cells(function (index, data, node) {
                            if (api.row(index).data().LastModified == null && api.row(index).data().timelogId != null) {
                                return true;
                            }
                            else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }, 6, { page: 'current' })
                        .data()
                        .reduce(function (a, b) {
                            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                        }, 0);

                    var cTotal = api
                        .cells(function (index, data, node) {
                            if (api.row(index).data().LastModified != null && api.row(index).data().timelogId != null || api.row(index).data().timelogId == null && parseInt(api.row(index).data().rateTotal) > 0) {
                                return true;
                            }
                            else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }, 6, { page: 'current' })
                        .data()
                        .reduce(function (a, b) {
                            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                        }, 0);

                    $(api.column(6).footer()).html(
                        "C(" + parseInt(cTotal).toFixed(0).toString().secondsToHHMMSS() + ")" + "<br/> U(" + parseInt(uTotal).toFixed(0).toString().secondsToHHMMSS() + ")"
                    );
                },
                "columns": [
                    {
                        "data": "isJoined",
                        "render": function (data, type, row) {
                            if (row.isJoined == 1) {
                                return '<i class="fa fa-fw f-s-10 m-r-5 fa-circle text-primary"></i>';
                            }
                            else {
                                return "";
                            }
                        }
                    },
                {
                    "data": "StartDate",
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {
                        return moment(data).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm").toString().trim();
                    }
                },
                {
                    "data": "EndDate",
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {
                        return moment(data).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
                    }
                },
                { "data": "fileRef" },
                { "data": "CategoryName" },
                { "data": "Notes" },
                {
                    "data": "BillableMinutes",
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {
                        if (row.rateTotal > 0 ) {
                            return data.toString().secondsToHHMMSS();
                        }
                        else {
                            var x = (data / 60);
                            return x.toFixed(2);
                        }

                    }
                },
                { "data": "rateTotal" },
                { "data": "disbursementTotal" }
                ],
                "createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {

                    if (data.LastModified == null && data.timelogId != null) {
                        $(row).addClass('redClass');
                    }
                },
                "deferRender": true,
                autoWidth: false,
                bAutoWidth: false,
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                paging: false,
                select: true,
                responsive: true,
            select: {
                style: 'multi'
            },
            buttons: [
                { extend: 'copyHtml5', footer: true },
                { extend: 'excelHtml5', footer: true },
                { extend: 'csvHtml5', footer: true },
                { extend: 'pdfHtml5', footer: true }
                ],
                columnDefs: [
                    {
                        targets: 5,
                        render: $.fn.dataTable.render.ellipsis(50, true, true)
                    },
                    { "width": "5px", "targets": 0 },
                    { "width": "135px", "targets": 1 },
                    { "width": "135px", "targets": 2 },
                    { "width": "1px", "targets": 3 },
                    { "width": "1px", "targets": 4 },
                    { "width": "400px", "targets": 5 },
                    { "width": "2px", "targets": 6 },
                    { "width": "1px", "targets": 7 },
                    { "width": "1px", "targets": 8 }
                ]
            });
```

The below listed code is how i do row grouping when the datatable is initialized, but i need to have this in a seperate button so when the user clicks the button it would only group then

```
"drawCallback": function (settings) {
    var api = this.api();
    var rows = api.rows({ page: 'current' }).nodes();
    var last = null;

    api.column(3, { page: 'current' }).data().each(function (group, i) {
        if (last !== group) {
            $(rows).eq(i).before(
                '<tr class="group"><td colspan="5">' + group + '</td></tr>'
            );

            last = group;
        }
    });
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a few more days of searching the internet i have not found a solution, but instead i created a global variable of type bool, so when the datatable is drawn it looks in the drawcall back function to see if the global variable is set to true or not, and depending on the condition it will either group or not, so i draw the table everytime after the user has clicked the button that he/she would like to group

```
"drawCallback": function (settings) {
if(groupBy == true){

var api = this.api();
var rows = api.rows({ page: 'current' }).nodes();
var last = null;

api.column(3, { page: 'current' }).data().each(function (group, i) {
    if (last !== group) {
        $(rows).eq(i).before(
            '<tr class="group"><td colspan="5">' + group + '</td></tr>'
        );

        last = group;
    }

}

});
},
```